# Automation to create separate data extensions of bounced contacts for each of our Business Units (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, automation, data-views

I want to run a _Bounce data view in our Enterprise BU (Marketing Cloud), and then filter the data by Business Unit for each of our 120 Business Units. Is there a way to automate it to create one filtered data extension by BU for each of the BUs without manually doing them? Can I reference a Data Extension that lists all our BUs in a query, for example?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SSJS script to create a filtered Data Extension:
[Server Side JavaScript to create a filtered data extension?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/162428/server-side-javascript-to-create-a-filtered-data-extension)

However, a filtered data extension will still require you to manually refresh it, each time you want it to reflect the referenced DE it filters. You might prefer to create a number of filter definitions and filter activities programatically. Both cases are described here: [Create Filter Definition via WSProxy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/260225/create-filter-definition-via-wsproxy) as well as here: [Creation of a Filter Activity via API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/185437/creation-of-a-filter-activity-via-api)

If you want to add these programatically to an automation, you can use the REST API, described with an example in this blog post:
https://www.ssjsdocs.xyz/automation-studio/activities/add.html